# Insert element into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lists have a very simple method to insert elements:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.insert(2,66)
print a
[1, 2, 66, 3, 4]
```

For a `numpy` array I could do:

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
a_l = a.tolist()
a_l.insert(2,66)
a = np.asarray(a_l)
print a
[1 2 66 3 4]
```

but this is very convoluted.

Is there an `insert` equivalent for `numpy` arrays?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), though unlike `list.insert` it returns a new array because arrays in NumPy have fixed size.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
>>> np.insert(a, 2, 66)
array([ 1,  2, 66,  3,  4])
```

Comment: That is very intuitive, I don't know why I didn't think of trying it. Thank you very much @Ashwini!

Comment: More about numpy.insert is here https://medium.com/@panjeh/numpy-insert-prepend-element-to-numpy-array-with-axis-parameter-875296ed87af

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to insert items in consequent indices, as a more optimized way you can use `np.concatenate()` to concatenate slices of the array with your intended items:

For example in this case you can do:

```
In [21]: np.concatenate((a[:2], [66], a[2:]))
Out[21]: array([ 1,  2, 66,  3,  4])
```

Benchmark (5 time faster than `insert` ):

```
In [19]: %timeit np.concatenate((a[:2], [66], a[2:]))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.insert(a, 2, 66)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.86 us per loop
```

And here is a benchmark with larger arrays (still 5 time faster):

```
In [22]: a = np.arange(1000)

In [23]: %timeit np.concatenate((a[:300], [66], a[300:]))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 us per loop                                              

In [24]: %timeit np.insert(a, 300, 66)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.72 us per loop
```

Comment: Never would've thought that using `np.concatenate()` was faster. Thank you Kasramvd!

Comment: @Gabriel You're welcome. That's actually because that `np.concatenate` need really fewer operations for doing this task rather than `insert` which will find the index first do a lot of checks and creates the new ones.

Comment: `concatenate` is compiled code, `insert` is a relatively complicated Python function (which you can study with `np.source(np.insert)`).

Comment: @hpaulj You mean C is only 5 time faster than python? At first I thought that this might be the reason but the difference in run times seems just like a difference in functionality.

Comment: After trying to replicate `insert` for the simplest insertion case, I think most of the extra time is due to its greater generality.  The core task of copying several slices of `a` to the `new` array takes about the same time as with `concatenate`.  But it spends more time setting things up and manipulating the slicing tuple.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, that's more sensible now!

Answer (score -1):

To add elements to a numpy array you can use the method 'append' passing it the array and the element that you want to add. For example:

`import numpy as np
 dummy = []
 dummy = np.append(dummy,12)`

this will  create an empty array and add the number '12' to it

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP question. Since the OP wanted to insert at an arbitrary position and not only at the end.