# How to insert multiple elements in numpy array using np.concatenate()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43184184/7110180) is already an answer for inserting one element in `numpy` array where `np.concatenate()` dominates over `np.insert()`(`np.concatenate()` takes less time than `np.insert()`). But I am unable to use it to insert elements in multiple positions. Here is an example --

```
cell = np.array([1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5])
place = np.argwhere(cell == np.amax(cell)).flatten().tolist()
cell = np.insert(cell, place, 0)
```

How can I use np.concatenate() for the same?

Comment: For that sample, `place` is empty. What's that command supposed to do for `place`?

Comment: @Divakar my bad. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.insert` (e.g. source like on docs).  It uses different strategies depending the number of insertion points.  While the possibilities are numerous, the basic principles are simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [178]: cell = np.array([1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5])
In [179]: place = np.argwhere(cell == np.amax(cell)).flatten().tolist()
In [180]: place
Out[180]: [3, 4, 6, 9]
In [181]: np.insert(cell, place, 0)
Out[181]: array([1, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5])
In [182]: np.concatenate([cell[:3],[0],cell[3:4],[0],cell[4:6],[0],cell[6:9],[0] ,cell[9:]])
Out[182]: array([1, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5])
```

Constructing the concatante list could be generalized with some sort of list iteration over the `place` values.  Details are left to the reader.

`insert`, with multiple insertions, uses a `mask` approach, which we can reverse engineer:

Where did it insert the 0s?

```
In [193]: res = np.insert(cell, place, 0)
In [194]: np.where(res==0)
Out[194]: (array([ 3,  5,  8, 12], dtype=int32),)
```

That's the same as adding 0,1,2,3 to place:

```
In [195]: np.arange(n)+place
Out[195]: array([ 3,  5,  8, 12])
```

make a target array and mask array:

```
In [196]: out = np.zeros(len(cell)+n, dtype=cell.dtype)
In [197]: mask = np.ones(len(out), dtype=bool)
```

use the mask to define where we insert the original values

```
In [198]: mask[Out[195]]=False
In [199]: out[mask] = cell
In [200]: out
Out[200]: array([1, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5])
```

Since the insertion value is 0, we don't need to do anything more.

I suggested in the previous answer that `concatenate` was faster than insert because `insert` is more general and takes more time to set things up.  That may be the case as well.  But I don't expect a bit improvement in time.

---

Generalized concatenate

```
In [235]: catlist = [cell[:place[0]],[0]]
In [236]: for i in range(n-1):
     ...:     catlist.append(cell[place[i]:place[i+1]])
     ...:     catlist.append([0])
     ...:     
In [237]: catlist.append(cell[place[-1]:])
In [238]: np.concatenate(catlist)
Out[238]: array([1, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you.This is a nice approach, but the problem is I have to deal with 10^18 elements and that's why I am trying to implement `concatenate()`, otherwise I am okay with `insert()`. If you have any better solution that will take less time than `insert()`, than it will be very helpful to me. I have tried `concatenate()` with `for` loop, but it takes nearly ~500 sec(for 10^9 elements) for inserting one by one element. Thank you once again.

Comment: If `cell` is large compared to `place`, I expect the `concatenate` approach (see my last edit) will be faster because it works with big slices of `cell`.  But if the  slices are small and numerous, then the masked copy as done by `insert` is probably faster.

Comment: I had exactly tried what you said in your last edit. As you said, here place is not small. So `insert` will help me. Thank you.